# What is the correct way to check object's property if object not undefined in angular 2 template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a confusion for using between two different ways for checking the length property of an object when not undefined in angular 2 template.

**Method 1:**

```
<div *ngIf="obj && obj.length">
    <!--Some code-->
</div>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<div *ngIf="obj?.length">
    <!--Some code-->
</div>
```

Both these code works, but my question is, are there any problems that may occur if I choose Method 2 over Method 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both does the same, whereas the second one is minified version of the former code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to check f variable is not null and not undefined

```
if (obj) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the first Method is

```
more :
```

as the 
`.length` 
might be undefined on initial object

```
`*ngIf="obj`
```